# Python gtalk client code not working

Tags: python, linux, xmpp

I am trying to run this code to make a gtalk  client but it is not running. i a new to this and i guess i a doing some silly mistake.please help me out. also please tell me how to remove these warnings

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 

import xmpp 
import hashlib

user="username@gmail.com"
password="password"
server="gmail.com"

jid = xmpp.JID(user) 
connection = xmpp.Client(server,debug=[]) 
connection.connect() 
result = connection.auth(jid.getNode(), password,"LFY-client") 

connection.sendInitPresence() 

while connection.Process(1): 
    pass


The code is giving following error :


/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/xmpp/auth.py:24: DeprecationWarning: the sha module is deprecated; use the hashlib module instead
  import sha,base64,random,dispatcher,re
/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/xmpp/auth.py:26: DeprecationWarning: the md5 module is deprecated; use hashlib instead
  import md5
/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/xmpp/transports.py:308: DeprecationWarning: socket.ssl() is deprecated.  Use ssl.wrap_socket() instead.
  tcpsock._sslObj    = socket.ssl(tcpsock._sock, None, None)
```

Answer (score 1):

Those are warnings not errors, and they are not caused by your code, the `xmpp` module is using some deprecated modules, I would recommend that you upgrade it.